# Volume form of warped product $(0, \infty) \times \mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ and volume of a ball in this space

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, volume

> Consider the warped product $(0, \infty) \times \mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ with the metric given by $$g = dr^2 + (\phi(r))^2 g_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}}$$
>
> **I want to compute the volume of a ball of radius $s$ centered at the origin in this space. The book I'm reading claims it is given by**:
>
> $$
> \operatorname{Vol}(B(O, s))=n \omega_{n} \int_{0}^{s} \phi(r)^{n-1} d r \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ (1)
> $$
>   **where $n\omega_{n}$ denotes the volume form of the unit euclidean $(n-1)$-sphere. Further, it states that under the hypotheses**
>
> $C^{-1} r^{1 / 2} \leq \phi(r) \leq C r^{1 / 2}$, $\phi^{\prime}(r)=O\left(r^{-1/2}\right)$ and $\phi^{\prime \prime}(r)=O\left(r^{-3 / 2}\right)$
>   and for $s \geq 1$, we will have that:
>
> $$
> \operatorname{Vol}(B(O, s)) \approx \int_{0}^{s} r^{\frac{n-1}{2}} d r \approx s^{\frac{n+1}{2}}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ (2)
> $$

So it would appear that:

$$
\operatorname{Vol}(B(O, s))= \int_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}} \int_{0}^{s} dV$$

where $dV$ would be the volume form of this warped product. But if this is correct, why is it so (and if not, how can I get to the formula presented)? And how do I compute this volume form (why does it apparently equal $\phi(r)^{n-1}$?)? I'm lost on how to compute it for a warped product. Any help here would be very appreciated (and please, give as many details as possible).

My other question is: how can one go from $(1)$ to $(2)$? I don't see how the hypotheses mentioned allow me to approximate $\phi$ in this manner.

---

**UPDATE:** Following Ted Shifrin's suggestion, I tried the cases $n = 2$ and $n = 3$. For $n = 2$, since the metric on $\mathbb{S}^1$ is indistinguishable from that of $\mathbb{R}$, it's easy to compute that $g$ is given by the matrix

$$
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}{1} & {0} \\ {0} & {(\phi(r))^2}\end{array}\right)
$$

for $n = 3$, we get:

$$
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}{1} & {0} & {0} \\ {0} & {(\phi(r))^2} & {0} \\ {0} & {0} & {(\phi(r))^2 \sin^2(\theta)} \\ \end{array}\right)
$$

It was then easy to see that for the general case, the matrix for $g$ will be given by:

$$
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}{1} & {} \\ {} & {(\phi(r))^2 g_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}}}\end{array}\right)
$$

where the unfilled spaces correspond to zeroes. So the volume of a ball would be given by:

$$
\operatorname{Vol}(B(O, s))= \int_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}} \int_{0}^{s} dV$$

but $dV = \sqrt{\operatorname{det} g }\  dx_1 \ \cdots dx_{n-1} \ dr$ and since $r$ is independent of all the other $x_1, \cdots, x_{n-1}$ and $\sqrt{\operatorname{det} g } = \sqrt{\operatorname{det}(\phi(r))^2 g_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}}} = (\phi(r))^{n-1}$, we have exactly:

$$
\operatorname{Vol}(B(O, s))=n \omega_{n} \int_{0}^{s} \phi(r)^{n-1} d r \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ 
$$

as for the other question, I think it deserves another different post to solve it.

Comment: Have you worked this out just for the case of polar coordinates in the plane or spherical coordinates in $\Bbb R^3$? What are the metric expressions in this format in those cases?

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes, see my edits. And thanks for the suggestion! As for the last question, it's still unsolved, but I'll make another post for it.

Comment: The last bit is immediate from the first extra hypothesis. The rest is extraneous.

Comment: @TedShifrin I know the first extra hypothesis says $\lim_{r \to \infty } \frac{\phi(r)}{\sqrt{r}}$ is constant, but why does that allow me to approximate $\phi(r)$ in that integral when I don't know how big or small $r$ and $C$ is? And why does $s \geq 1$ matter?

Comment: I was interpreting this as an asymptotic formula as $s\to\infty$, with $\approx \cdot$ meaning $O(\cdot)$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Oh, *that* makes sense (but the book didn't make it clear). Thanks! If you want to post an answer I'll accept it.